# Trying to replace any entire cell in an Excel sheet that contains a ","

Tags: excel, replace

I'm sure this is a fairly basic solution, but I am trying to recode some survey data with multiple possible responses and have been unable to identify a way to easily replace any cell which contains a comma (","). The data is currently in only one column and I want to replace any cell with a comma to a "1".
Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could press ctrl + h, put in the upper textbox asterisk comma asterisk and in the second textbox the "1" and replace all button.
This will replace every cell contains a comma to 1 in the sheet.